# How to log PHP function calls (arguments, return value) defined in a PHP file to database?

Tags: php

I have read [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850756/how-to-log-all-calls-to-a-function-in-php-mail-function). My problem is similar: to debug some problems, I need to log all calls to functions in a source file `includes/foo.php` to database:

```
<?php
function f1($arg1, $arg2) {
    return $arg1 . "x" . $arg2;
}
...
function f9($foo, $bar=array(), $baz=0) {
    return array(...);
}
```

What is the simplest way to do this? I've thought of moving `includes/foo.php` to `includes/foo.php_orig`, renaming all functions in that source (e.g. f1 to f1__orig, and so on), then put in my own wrapper `includes/foo.php`:

```
<?php
include "includes/logger.php";
include "includes/foo.php_orig";
function f1($arg1, $arg2) {
    $res = f1__orig($arg1, $arg2);
    log_fcall(array($arg1, $arg2), $res);
    return $res;
}
...
function f9($foo, $bar=array(), $baz=0) {
    $res = f9__orig($foo, $bar, $baz);
    log_fcall(array($foo, $bar, $baz), $res);
    return $res;
}
```

But this feels so tedious and manual. Does PHP offer another mechanism? Or at least, some other constructs to ease the pains.

Comment: You should probably have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php Instead of writing these wrapper functions, I would probably rather copy a one-liner that writes the output of debug_backtrace to a file at the beginning of each of those nine functions.

Comment: Logging backtraces is still a pain. You could be much more comfortable using *xdebug* in conjuction with an IDE having a builtin debugger client, e.g. *netbeans, eclipse, phpstorm*. You can view call stacks and inspect variables at runtime step by step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Vx8TnNdQ6M

Answer (score 0):

One way you *could* do this is using some wrapper magic and eval. This is not to say you *should* do it, since if this is for debugging, there are much better tools, e.g. `debug_baktrace` mentioned by 04FS in the comment. Additionally, `eval` may be disabled for you, depending on where you host your PHP code.

The wrapper would take the intended function name, and an anonymous function, like so:

```php
$wrapped = array();

function logWrap($name, $func) {
  global $wrapped;
  $wrappedIndex = count($wrapped);
  $wrapped[] = $func;
  eval(
    "function ${name}() {"
    . "global \$wrapped;"
    . "\$args = func_get_args();"
    . "\$res = call_user_func_array(\$wrapped[${wrappedIndex}], \$args);"
    . "log_fcall(\$args, \$res);"
    . "return \$res;"
    . "}");
}
```

Then you can simply wrap your functions like so:

```php
logWrap("f1", function($arg1, $arg2) {
    return $arg1 . "x" . $arg2;
});
```